# Cypress visit uncaught reference

Tags: cypress, uncaught-exception

I'm trying to load "https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/".

When the URL is loaded, I see `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined".`

Is there some configuration I need to set?

[image: error image]
my code is:

```
describe('My firts cypress', () =>{    
    it ('navegate to FUT web app', () =>{        
        cy.visit('https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/')        
    })
})
```

[after add uncaught:exception to return false...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuEz4.png)

Comment: There are lot of front end errors. The beauty of cypress is that it clearly states that it is from the application code. Speak to the developer who was involved in the frontend code

Comment: Are you able to load that page in browser without cypress?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says it is not from Cypress but from your applcation. When you open console you should be able to look into the details. To bypass this error you can

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    // returning false here prevents Cypress from
    // failing the test
    return false
  })
```

to your index.js under support folder.

This will stop failing your test if there is uncaught exception. See [cypress doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#To-turn-off-all-uncaught-exception-handling).

Comment: now I got a "unsuported html" from that page, it means i can't use cypress for this project? I'm trying with selenium too..

Comment: can you add more description about your errors with screenshots? thanks

Comment: I edited my question... can you check the screenshot?

Comment: Even when you visit the the url in chrome it has the tag unsupported html. But i see the issue that cypress won't be able to load the page. Also I found the webpage has some problems loading even in chrome and firefox. (shows black sometimes and login won't work). Probably you have to solve these issues first before you can start a test. Or I can see the login page goes to another url you might be able to skip this page check if it is not mandatory?